# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with NelmioCorsBundle

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

Hi i have this configuration for NelmioCorsBundle in Symfony framework:

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/note/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['X-Custom-Auth']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
```

I still get **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I made two virtual hosts on my local machine one virtual host is client, other virtual host is restAPI.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone have the same issue as i here is the answer.

I use Ubuntu. **NelmioCorsBundle was already working the problem was with project folder privileges, when composer is installing this bundle it needs to clear app cache. If you don't set write permissions it won't be able to write in the cache directory.**

It needs to add new configurations and write it in cache.

This was problem, after this everything worked.

I hope this helps.

Comment: What kind of errors were you getting to lead you to discover this? I am having a similar issue and I tried your advice of moving things around, but it hasn't helped. I also have the added complicated of trying to do it inside of a vagrant box. Anyway, if I know what errors to look for, I can try and tell if I am having the same issue.

Comment: My app is also inside vagrant box. I wasn't getting any errors, that was strange... Give 655 permissions to your cache folder. Try to empty cache for   prod and dev environment.

Comment: One more thing @Jayd in symfony get all params from post method with this method $request->getContent()

Comment: Mine ended up being that I was using version `1.5.1` of the `nelmio/cors-bundle`. Because version `1.5.2` was broken, so I rolled back. But then I finally went back and put it as `^1.5` and did an update and it all seemed to work for me. So apparently `1.5.1` was also broken in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my config:

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '/api':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE','OPTIONS']
            max_age: 3600
```

works fine, the only difference is in allow_headers value and path. Try it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i found problem :)